# How do I parse XML web service in Swift?

Tags: xml, swift, nsxmlparser

I don't know how to parse in my below code..
Can someone

```
func callService(usr: String, pwdCode: String) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://inspect.dev.cbre.eu/SyncServices/api/jobmanagement/PlusContactAuthenticationPost")
    var xmlParse:NSString  = ""
    var data : NSData!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
     request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let dictionary = ["email": usr, "userPwd": pwdCode]
    var error: NSError?
    if let body = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: nil, error: &error) {
        request.HTTPBody = body
    } else {
        println("JSON error: \(error)")
    }

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

        // xmlParse=NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        // let data = (xmlParse as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        // NSXMLParser(data : NSData)

        // xmlParse=NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        // xmlParse=response
        // println(xmlParse)
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: BTW, it's a little unusual to see JSON request and XML response. Are you sure about that? Also, does the `data` returned look like valid XML?

Comment: yes, it is ...but we need to call third party webservice from our app..so we can't change it..@rob , I am pasting me xml response below..Can you please check what could be done?

Comment: My Xml response will be like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><serviceresult><success>false</success><resultmessage>User not found in the system.</resultmessage></serviceresult>

Comment: Check out my project for parsing XML easily in Swift: https://github.com/borchero/WebParsing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `NSXMLParser` in your completion handler for the request:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (data, response, error) in

    if data == nil {
        println("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()

    // you can now check the value of the `success` variable here
}
task.resume()

// but obviously don't try to use it here here
```

Clearly, the above assumes that you have (a) defined your view controller to conform to `NSXMLParserDelegate` and (b) have implemented the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods, e.g. something like:

```
var elementValue: String?
var success = false

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if elementName == "success" {
        elementValue = String()
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
    if elementValue != nil {
        elementValue! += string
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "success" {
        if elementValue == "true" {
            success = true
        }
        elementValue = nil
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    println("parseErrorOccurred: \(parseError)")
}
```

Comment: thanks Rob..I will have a look today and let you know.

Comment: thanks @Rob...it has resolved my issue..Just one more question..when i am printing this value on my regular function 'callService' it is giving me 'nil' ..how can i access elementValue in my method?

Comment: Well, I `nil` the `elementValue` (so that `foundCharacters` will only be appending characters between the `<success>` and `</success>` tags). If you want to save it, you could theoretically create another variable, and save a copy of `elementValue` inside that `if elementName == success` statement of `didEndElement`. (Note, do _not_ just remove the line that sets `elementValue` to `nil`, as that will break my routine: Save the value as I outlined above.) But I don't know why you'd feel like you need to save the value, as the `success` variable captures whether `true` was found or not...

Comment: hi rob.Can u please give me ur email address..I wanted to give my whole code to you and check if i am missing something or not..Because when i am declaring the "success" as a global variable than it is giving me  wronge result

Comment: Put it out on gist.github.com or pastie.org or similar site…

Answer (score 9):

For anyone still looking, here is the code I used that worked quite well to convert the xml response into Dictionaries/Arrays, thanks to the [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash/blob/master/Source/SWXMLHash.swift) class...

**UPDATED SWIFT 2.0**

```
    let baseUrl = "http://www.example.com/file.xml"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseUrl)!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    var err: NSError?

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if data == nil {
            print("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

        if let definition = xml["entry_list"]["entry"][0]["def"].element?.text {
            // ...
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            // use main thread for UI updates
        })

    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: I am not able to get dictionary from xml.

Comment: Perfect solution! Only one little thing: add "!" after data in: let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Class Created below To get Dictionary From XML data.

https://github.com/Bhaavik/BDXmlParser

You need To add that class 
and just call Below Function for Dictionary response

```
  let objXmlParser = BbXmlParser()
  let  dictResponse  =  objXmlParser.getdictionaryFromXmlData(data!)
                        print(dictResponse)
```

And here You go with dictionary. :)